# Is is possible to bypass GPO on external USB drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, group-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Temporarily remove Group Policy in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/127994/temporarily-remove-group-policy-in-windows-7)

I have an external drive that I need to get some source from, and the GPO is preventing me from using the drive.  Is it possible to temporarily override that setting via the registry or similar place?  I'm trying to avoid moving all of this to dropbox tonight just to bring it down tomorrow.

Comment: Have you asked the people in charge of your Group Policy if they can help?  Circumventing GP can be a big no-no at many work places.

Comment: If you are not a domain administrator then you need to ask your local IT staff for an exception. chmod has the correct answer: SuperUser cannot support or assist in attempts to circumvent specific corporate IT policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, well, you'll need to run regmon to figure out what policy is being applied. That will give you a list-- then, you'll need to prevent it from being applied at the registry level.
Or, better yet, here's a guide from technet: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/04/30/circumventing-group-policy-settings.aspx