# How to not receive command from domain control to force using proxy

Tags: proxy

My domain controller always forces me to use a proxy, and my IE keeps recovering back the setting even when I clear it.

How can I ignore the domain controller when it sets my proxy again?

Answer (score 1):

Your settings come enforced by a group policy object.
The right way is to ask the domain administrators to exclude your workstation from the policy.
The alternate way is, if you have administrative access of the local machine, find the registry location of the setting and change permissions by removing "modify" rights to the "system" user.
You can find more details on the following superuser question: [Temporarily remove Group Policy in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/127994/temporarily-remove-group-policy-in-windows-7)
It addresses a different gpo setting but the method is the same.
It involves using the killpoll tool which enables you to temporarily remove policy restriction for the current user.